# Android Studio: need to change Version number, but failed to resolve if I do

Tags: android, gradle

I am rather new to Android studio, and upon searching this site for a fixture to my problem, I seem to run into an entirely new one.

The main issue I get when I try to sync my Grandle files is usually "Please update version to (version number)"

I do this, but to which point I will get one or more errors that says "Failed to resolve: [app name and version]"

What would I do at this point? Nothing seems to make sense right now considering everything else I have found based on this should have fixed it.

My code is as followed

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "twitchy.groupchatapp"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thank you very much for any assitance
*Note: The code is before I changed each to have the same version number
Below is the error I receive when I do

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:11.4.2
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:11.4.2
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:11.4.2
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

Added the Build level Gradle now

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: change  com.android.support:design:27.1.0 and com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0

Comment: Please add your other Gradle file to the question

Comment: By the way, your Firebase UI version is significantly outdated https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/README.md#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `com.android.support:` projects nor FirebaseUI have version 11.4.2 dependencies.

These must match the compileSdk version at the top of the file.

For your use case,

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
```

Then, ConstraintLayout, [look at the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

This line is correct, and does not match your error.

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

That 11.4.2 number is for [Google Play services, and Firebase only](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), and should be updated accordingly if you're starting a new app.

For example,

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```

Firebase UI version [must be compatible with those, not the same](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/README.md#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, but even following you directions, I updated everything to the version it should be but I still get it telling me that the repositories are in correct, or that it cant find the version I asked for even when its exactly what it is telling me to do.

Comment: Scratch that, everything you said was actually correct and I had an unnoticed error within the group, and upon correcting that it fixed all of my troubles. Thank you very much!